# How to programmatically open 10 cmd windows, activate conda virtual environment, and run a python script with arguments in each window

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I have a directory with 10 files. So ten different times I want to run a set of commands in a new cmd window, and I want the windows to persist on my screen while the script is executing. I'm accessing an API, so this is the fastest (easiest) way for me to "parallelize" my script. This is the gist of the set of commands that will run in each window.

```
User>activate environment_name
(environment_name) User>python update_contacts.py file_name
```

Right now I have this which works fine

```
os.system("start /B start cmd.exe @cmd /k activate environment_name")
```

But I don't know how to have the newly activated environment execute a python script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Here we go:

```
os.system('start /B start cmd.exe @cmd /k "activate environment_name & python update_contacts.py file_name"')
```

Comment: While possible, this is not the fastest and certainly not the easiest way to 'parallelize' your script.

Comment: By fastest I mean shortest development to completion time. Doing it this way will require me to write no additional code and it will make it take 3 hours to run instead of 30. So please no advice on how I should change the way I want to do the thing; I'm only interested in an actual answer to my question. I added that line because I want to avoid discussing the topic you have brought up entirely.

Comment: You can activate the environment just once in the current shell. Then, for example, use `start "Update Contacts (1)" python.exe -i "path\to\update_contacts.py" "path\to\file"`. Each Python instance will run attached to a new console. When it's done, it should drop into the REPL due to the `-i` command-line argument, which keeps the console from being immediately destroyed.

Comment: @eryksun Hey, this works great. My addition to the question works fine but yours does much better. Add it as an answer to my question and I'll accept it.